# Certificate issue using WCF with SSL

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a service that a 3rd party company is publishing. For the authentication part, we use two certificates, one with a public key and one with a private key.

I've made an console application just to test the certificates in differente stores, with the following possibilities:

- Location: Current User; Store: Personal
- Location: Local Machine; Store: Personal (installed with admin user. I don't have admin permissions)

It was working until I've changed my computer to another this week. I've tested on other machines and it's working on both configurations. But mine only works when I try the 'Current User Location'. Why? My application needs to use the 'Local Machine Location'.

The only possibility I can think about is some kind of permission. But I'm not finding any clue on web. All the similar links say something about the bindings, wrong certificates, overriding ServiceCallBack, etc.

Someone knows if any permission is needed to use the certificate from LocalMachine?

Obs: the application can find the certificate, but when it uses I got the following error:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'name-of-certificate'
```

Note: I know there is other posts similar to this, but the problem/scenario is really different.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the identity of the application pool has to rights to read the private key of the certificate from the Local Machine store.

To add the permission, go to the Certificate snapin, right click the certificate, select All Tasks and Manage private keys. From there, add the application pool identity.

Also, as always, make sure that the application pool's "Load user profile" setting is set to true.